# I am getting error 6: overflow. Why?

Tags: excel, vba

This is a function that is in my program. In the while loop, i'm getting an overflow. Why? How do i fix this?

```
Sub durationhours(ByVal sheetname As String, ByVal counter60M As Integer)

Dim j As Integer, matchcounter As Integer, k As Integer, runningtotal As Integer

j = 8: matchcounter = 0: runningtotal = 0

For counter = 7 To counter60M

    While Worksheets(sheetname).Cells(counter, 2) = Worksheets(sheetname).Cells(j, 2)
        j = j + 1
        matchcounter = matchcounter + 1
    Wend

    If IsEmpty(Worksheets(sheetname).Cells(j, 2)) Then j = j + 3

    For k = counter To (counter + matchcounter)
        runningtotal = runningtotal + Worksheets(sheetname).Cells(counter, 10)
        'here is where you do the calculations for the duration hours
    Next k

    Worksheets(sheetname).Cells(counter, 11) = runningtotal

    counter = j: j = j + 1: matchcounter = 0: runningtotal = 0


Next counter
```

Comment: Because one of your integer variable exceeds the max value it can hold. Look at the error when it happens and see what value is in the variable. Then figure out why and fix it.

Comment: Integers are limited to `32767` in VBA, use `Long` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely getting that error for one (or combination) of three reasons:

**1)** Your `While` loop never escapes

**2)** `counter60M` is an extremely large number

**3)** `matchcounter` is an extremely large number

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Dim j As Integer, matchcounter As Integer, k As Integer, runningtotal As Integer
```

To

```
Dim j As Long, matchcounter As Long, k As Long, runningtotal As Long
```

then you should be fine